# IM (Instant Message) Address Standard

Tags: email, validation, instant-messaging, rfc

Dear stack overflowers,

I am not sure if this is the best place for this question, but I figured I'd give it a shot.

I am currently working on an API that will allow consumers to read/write data about users. i.e. `name`, `emails`, `phoneNumbers`, etc. And, as you could guess by the title, I am also storing `ims`.

Since users may contain multiple `im` addresses that belong to different services (e.g. skype, google talk, AIM, etc.), there is a `type` attribute associated with each `im` address.

I am at the point where I am attempting to validate the user attributes, and when I arrived to `ims` I was unable to find a formal specification, or normative document that dictates how these should be formatted/validated.

My question is the following:

Is there a general format that `im` URI's follow?

*note:*I have stumbled upon [RFC 3861](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-impp-srv-04#page-4) that touches on `im` addresses. But it seems like this isn't a standard. Additionally, there is only one example here that has the following format:

> im:fred@example.com

Since emails are effectively unique identifiers, it seems reasonable that they could be represented in this way.

Could anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 0):

After looking in several sites, I was unable to find a standard that applies to all IM providers. I even looked in some API documentation (Yahoo and Jabber) without any luck. If anyone else finds anything that leads them to think any different, please share the knowledge. But as for right now, it appears I am out of luck...